# git commits into html filr through jenkins

Tags: html, git, perl, jenkins

I am passing a HTML file through Jenkins from build to production servers.
I am injecting the build number into the HTML file using perl.

Now I also want to inject the git commits into the HTML page.
The below is how I injected build number in place of the `{BUILD_VERSION}` in the HTML page.

```
perl -pi -e 's/{BUILD_VERSION}/Android_IT_ACCEPTANCE - $ENV{build}/g' index.html
```

Now, I want git commits in release notes page. I tried this. It didn't workout.

```
perl -pi -e 's/{RELEASE_NOTES}/Release Notes: $ENV{Change}/g' index.html
```

Comment: What happens? Is the `{RELEASE_NOTES}' replaced at all or is it still in place? Try to add `export >> index.html` to see the list of environment variables available.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding you, because it's unclear how you came up with `build` in the environment, but looking at the [Jenkins environment variable docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) it kind of looks like you want to be using these:

- `BUILD_NUMBER` The current build number, such as "153"
- `BUILD_ID`        The current build id, such as "2005-08-22_23-59-59" (YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss, defunct since version 1.597)
- `BUILD_URL`       The URL where the results of this build can be found (e.g. `http://buildserver/jenkins/job/MyJobName/666/`)
- ...
- `GIT_COMMIT`       For Git-based projects, this variable contains the Git hash of the commit checked out for the build (like ce9a3c1404e8c91be604088670e93434c4253f03) ﻿(all the GIT_* variables require git plugin)
- `GIT_URL`            For Git-based projects, this variable contains the Git url (like `git@github.com:user/repo.git or [https://github.com/user/repo.git]`)
- `GIT_BRANCH`       For Git-based projects, this variable contains the Git branch that was checked out for the build (normally origin/master)

So maybe you're looking for something more like:

```
perl -pi -e '
  s/{BUILD_VERSION}/Android_IT_ACCEPTANCE - $ENV{BUILD_NUMBER}/g;
  s/{RELEASE_NOTES}/Release Notes: $ENV{GIT_COMMIT}/g;
' index.html
```

Comment: i initialised build=BUILD_NUMBER.

Comment: @karthikk Good; so you also assigned something to `Change`? If so what didn't work in trying your substitution? If not, did you try my version of the substitution and are you sure `{BUILD_VERSION}` and `{RELEASE_NOTES}` appear in index.html before you perform this step?

Comment: yes, there is build version and release notes in index.html. but i think $Change isnt working